# Select row of data based on specific conditions from other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, multiple-columns

I have this data:

```
ID_OWN ID_PET KEY NAME
123    1      11  JOY
123    1      11  JOY
123    2      12  JOY
123    2      12  JOY
456    1      13  HELLO
456    1      13  MAMA
456    2      14  HELLO
456    2      14  MAMA
```

SCENARIO IS:

If I SELECT DISTINCT, **ID_OWN 123** will return 2 rows of data.

But for **ID_OWN 456**, it will still return 4 rows of data, because column **NAME** has all different values.

What I want is, if **NAME** has different values under the same **ID_OWN**, then I want those **NAME** values to be sticked together, so it will return 2 rows of data too (or N rows of data based on no. of **ID_PET** under the same **ID_OWN**, in this case, they are 1 and 2)

Below is expected return data:

```
ID_OWN ID_PET KEY NAME
123    1      11  JOY
123    2      12  JOY
456    1      13  HELLO MAMA
456    2      14  HELLO MAMA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server, You can achieve it in this way, [demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=37fb8148ddbab8f3b85f48f295f52e8f)

```
;WITH cte_TempTable AS (
 SELECT DISTINCT ID_OWN, ID_PET, Key_Number, Name
 FROM TempTable
)
SELECT DISTINCT ID_OWN, ID_PET, Key_Number, SUBSTRING(
(
   SELECT ' ' + Name
   FROM cte_TempTable C1
   WHERE C1.ID_OWN = C2.ID_OWN AND C1.ID_PET = C2.ID_PET AND C1.Key_Number = C2.Key_Number
  FOR XML PATH ('')
), 2, 1000) AS "nAME"
FROM cte_TempTable C2
```

**Output**

```
ID_OWN  ID_PET  Key_Number  nAME
123        1    11          JOY
123        2    12          JOY
456        1    13          HELLO MAMA
456        2    14         HELLO MAMA
```

Answer (score 0):

Use XML in combo with stuff

```
select distinct ID_OWN , ID_PET, [KEY],
STUFF((Select ' '+ NAME
from yourtable T1
where T1.ID_OWN =T2.ID_OWN and T1.ID_PET =T2.ID_PET  and T1.[KEY] =T2.[KEY] 
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as stickedName from yourtable  T2
```

Output is:

```
ID_OWN  ID_PET  KEY stickedName
123     1       11  JOY
123     2       12  JOY
456     1       13  HELLO,MAMA
456     2       14  HELLO,MAMA
```

[image]

Comment: You are missing `Key` column. So your code is not working correctly.

Comment: Did you try your code? I run your code then the result is incorrect. https://ibb.co/Xk5NLqy. You can see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60068914/9071943)

Comment: That's weird. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=58b66fdbb3d190b268126a14df6fa306

Answer (score 0):

If it is MySQL, you can use GROUP_CONCAT as below-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6f3158132ea2a0453ade3433955e4bf9)

```
SELECT ID_OWN,ID_PET,`Key`, group_CONCAT(NAME)
FROM  (
    SELECT DISTINCT ID_OWN,ID_PET,`Key`, NAME FROM your_table
)A
GROUP BY ID_OWN,ID_PET,`Key`
```

Comment: unfortunately im not using myaql... im using MS SQL Server ..